# Python Google News Script

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

```
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
import sys
f = open("googlenewsx.txt", "w")
keywordlist = ['Apple', 'Pear','Orange']
googlenews = GoogleNews()
for word in keywordlist:
    googlenews.search(word)
    googlenews.setTimeRange('15/05/2020','15/06/2020')
    googlenews.getpage(1)
    results = googlenews.result()
    listofres = []
    for ting in results:
        title = ting['title']
        date = ting['date']
        link = ting['link']
        listofres += [[title, date, link]]
        f.write("%s, %s, %s \n" %(title, date, link))
#print(listofres)
#f.close()
```

My code use the GoogleNews module on Python and will only work for the first term in the list. So it only searches the first word and keeps searching the first word. How can I get it to search each term in my list? I'm completely new to coding.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to search the keyword on page 1 only. You could use an index value (i=...) and search in each page. I'm foreign to this library so I had to have a quick search, I think you are not finding the keywords you are looking for in all pages so might have to expand your catalog of pages. Python-wise, there is nothing that happens to be wrong, syntax seems to be OK.